# Passwords and Delphi TZipFile

Tags: delphi, zip, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

Is Delphi XE5 TZipFile able to handle encrypted/password protected zip files? 
Or must users use third party software to handle this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Judging by the 4 hours of tumbleweed, no. You need delphi at least.

Comment: Jedi Code library has wrapper over 7 zip lib capable of zip and few other formats uniformly

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the source code for `System.Zip`, I see no indication of anything that would allow working with encrypted Zip files. There is no provision for specifying a password for either zipping or extracting files or creating a Zip archive.

You could always include support for encrypted archives using [Turbo Power Abbrevia](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpabbrevia/), open-sourced several years ago by Turbo Power. It's been updated to support XE5, according to the [SVN repository](http://sourceforge.net/p/tpabbrevia/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/) for the project at SourceForge. It's maintained quite well by the contributors to the project, comes with full source code, and is cross-platform (Windows, OS X, and Linux, at least - I don't see any indication of Android or iOS support).

Comment: 5 years later, is there still no feasible support for this if I may ask?

Comment: @Fero: A quick scan of the source doesn't show anything that has changed in regard to passwords.